# PHP can't find private variables

Tags: php, class, private

For some reason PHP can't find my private variables.

I get following error message

> *6 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _database in /var/www/simple-blog/models/database.php on line 24
>   PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/simple-blog/models/database.php:24

Line 24 is the line where I set $_database = $database.

```
class Database {

private $_database;
private $_mysqli;


public function connect(string $host, string $username, string $password, string $database) : bool
{
    $this->$_database = $database;

    $this->$_mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    if ($this->$_mysqli->connect_error) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
...
```

I tried removing that aready, but then PHP can't find the variable $_mysqli

Answer (score 3):

The way you used the variable is not correct. For more detail on php class variable have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Change `$this->$_database` to `$this->_database`.
Change `$this->$_mysql` to `$this->_mysql`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
$this->$_database = $database;
```

to

```
$this->_database = $database;
```

and

```
$this->$_mysqli
```

to

```
$this->_mysqli
```

and

```
$this->$_mysqli->connect_error
```

to

```
$this->_mysqli->connect_error
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the way of declaring the variaibles:

```
 $this->_database = $database;
```